# How can I convert a line number to byte offset?

Tags: c, bash, file

I have a file that stores one word on each line, I wish to know the byte offset of any of these words. How can I find that quickly in the terminal?

Answer (score 2):

1. To print byte offset of all lines

   ```
   grep --byte-offset "." filename
   ```
2. To print byte offset of a specific word

   ```
   grep --byte-offset "word" filename
   ```

Comment: In #1: prints byte offset of _non-empty_ lines. Otherwise use `grep --byte-offset '' filename` to get all lines.

Comment: Note that this is a GNU `grep` extension compared to POSIX `grep`, though BSD (Mac OS X) `grep` also supports it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit gniourf. I will make sure to cover all cases in future :).

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ printf("%4i: %s\n",c,$0); c+=length($0)+1 }' filename
```

Or specific word

```
awk '{ if($1 == "Specific Word") printf("%4i: %s\n",c,$0); c+=length($0)+1}' testa
```

Sorry for codestyle, but terminal one line can not be formatted.

Comment: Doesn't answer OP as it doesn't show byte offset, but character offset!